# Powershell script to Get how many items where created in a specific Timespan

Tags: powershell

I'm currently trying to create a Script that displays how many files were created in a specific Folder and its Subfolders within the last month.

Currently, it looks like This but that doesn't seem to work:

```
(Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Measure-Object).Count 
    | where-object {$_.CreationTime -gt (Get-Date).Date}
```

My plan is to create a script you run and then you can type in a start and an end date, and if you press enter it shows how many files were created in the specific timespan

Answer (score 0):

The measuring should be done after the filtering, not before :)

```bash
$monthsAgo = 1
@(Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -gt (Get-Date).AddMonths(-$monthsAgo) }).Count
```

If you want to do a filtering between a start date and an end date you would need to include a second condition, for example:

```bash
$start = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-2)
$end = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1)

@(Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File |
    Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -gt $start -and $_.CreationTime -lt $end }).Count
```